# Python ValueError exception - Name "a" is not defined error

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, try-catch

I am trying to implement a try exception in Python which when inputting a char/string instead of an int, catches the exception.

However, when inputting the letter 'a' the program crashes, returning the following error:

```
num = input('Enter integer number: ')   File "<string>", line 1, in
<module> NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

This is my code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':   #main function
    num = input('Enter integer number: ')
    try:
        num = int(num)
    except ValueError:
        print "Invalid input."
```

Comment: Since you are in `python 2.x`(assuming that because of `print`), try using `raw_input` instead of `input` and don't add [tag:python-3.x] to your tags.

Comment: If you are using pycharm, probably your interpreter is pointing to python 2.7. Try changing it to python3 and will solve the issue. You can change the interpreter in Preferences -> Project -> Python interpreter

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to catch a `ValueError` but the function is raising a `NameError` instead. So you're no catching it. Try:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':   #main function
    num = input('Enter integer number: ')
    try:
        num = int(num)
    except Exception as e:
        print "Invalid input: {}".format(e.message)
```

Comment: Actually, using `input` is the problem here. `input` acts as `eval` in python 2.x so that should be changed to `raw_input`. Casting int on char/string raises a ValueError which is what OP tries to achieve.

Comment: You're right. Then, you can say then that there are at least two problems. The goal of the author is to 'implement a try exception in Python'. So I looked at the problem catching the exception.

Answer (score 1):

from the documentation input() interprets the given input.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=input#input

so if you give the input as **"a"** it would interpret it as a string and proceed.
since you are give the value as **a**, it expects a variable named **a**.

if you directly want to use the user input, as suggested in the comments by @Lafexlos use **raw_input** instead.